# Programming project, ADT Lists

Tags: java, list, void

We recently switched professors and this new professor was under the impression that we had a wealth of knowledge we do not possess.

We have a programming project due and I would just like some clarification, if possible.

(From exercise 4.4) Write a method void interchange (List  l) which interchanges the         current element in the list and the one following it. (First make it work in the normal case; then, if you still have time, make sure it handles special cases, such as: the list is empty; the list has only one element; current is at the end of the list

(From exercise 4.6) Write a method void reverse (List  l) which reversed the order of items stored in the list. Again, make sure it works for any special cases you can think of.

(From exercise 4.7) Write a method List mergeLists (List l1, List l2)which takes two sorted Lists as input, producing a new List containing all the elements of both lists, also sorted. The new list is the return value for the method.

So I created a list

```
    ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
    numbers.add("Zero");
    numbers.add("One");
    numbers.add("Two");
    numbers.add("Three");
    System.out.println (numbers);
```

And so I'm assuming that under this I'm to make these 3 new methods. I'm just having a hard time following his instructions. I'm not asking anyone to do my work for me, I would just like some clarification on exactly what he wants us to do, and I can subsequently attempt to do research.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not ask your professor instead of a bunch of random internet strangers?

Comment: I've come to find that a) The people here are quite knowledgeable and b) I have asked him, a few people have and he told us to 'figure it out' as its not that hard. @John3136

Answer (score 0):

I think your professor is asking for something more abstract than what you did.

You are supposed to, first, define your own class representing a list element such as

```
class List {
  int data;
  List next;

}
```

Then you are given a list say `List myList`. It is supposed all elements are in there already.

Then you are supposed to write a function, say `void reverse(List list)`  that, given that `myList` would reverse it in place etc, etc.

Exercies like this are in many books. Your professor wants to give you some abstract knowledge which is more valuable than some particular language syntax.

Comment: Oh...I thought he wanted us to just edit a preexisting array. Alright thanks

Comment: well I cant make concrete sense of it, whatever. I'll figure it out somehow.

Comment: Concrete sense, gee.. Ok, they're often asking things like that at job interviews

Comment: Considering that I started programming maybe a month ago, I think that I'll fare well once I invest a few years into this. @Alex